# Why do PyRotationWarper.warp and PyRotationWarper.warpPoint appear to apply different transforms?

Tags: python, opencv

I have some K and R matrices I would like to apply to both an image and to a point somewhere in that image, such that the point is projected to the matched location in the output image. I am using part of an existing image stitching pipeline which heavily relies on the `cv2.PyRotationWarper` class. A working example looks like this:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
from skimage import data


img = data.cells3d()[34]
img = (255.0 * img / 2**16).astype(np.uint8)[0]
img = cv2.resize(img, (300, 200))
point = [200, 100]
K = np.array(
    [[863.5509, 0.0, 446.5], [0.0, 863.5509, 336.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]], dtype=np.float32
)

R = np.array(
    [
        [0.02657406, 0.99131364, -0.12880631],
        [-0.9981135, 0.01917798, -0.05832428],
        [-0.05534741, 0.13011324, 0.9899532],
    ],
    dtype=np.float32,
)

scale = 890.0
aspect = 1.0

warper = cv2.PyRotationWarper("spherical", scale * aspect)

# warp the image
_, warped_image = warper.warp(
    img,
    K,
    R,
    cv2.INTER_LINEAR,
    cv2.BORDER_REFLECT,
)

# warp the input point
warped_pt = warper.warpPoint(
    point,
    K,
    R,
)

w, h = img.shape[:2][::-1]

# check the maps to see where the transformed pixels came from
_, xmap, ymap = warper.buildMaps(
    (w, h),
    K,
    R,
)

# plot the example
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8))

axes[0, 0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
imx = axes[0, 1].imshow(xmap)
imy = axes[1, 0].imshow(ymap)
axes[1, 1].imshow(warped_image, cmap='gray')

axes[0, 0].add_patch(Circle(point, 3, color='red',))
axes[1, 1].add_patch(Circle(warped_pt, 3, color='red'))

axes[0, 0].set(title=f"original image; point: {point}")
axes[0, 1].set(title="xmap")
axes[1, 0].set(title="ymap")
axes[1, 1].set(title=f"warped image: point: [{warped_pt[0]:.2f}, {warped_pt[1]:.2f}]")
cbx = plt.colorbar(imx, ax=axes[0, 1], orientation="vertical")
cby = plt.colorbar(imy, ax=axes[1, 0], orientation="vertical")

plt.tight_layout()
```

But the point gets projected to a crazy location `[-353.75, 1582.54]` instead of where I'd expect: roughly `[100, 100]`. The debugging plot looks like this:
[image: debug_image]

It seems clear that I'm missing something here, maybe just not understanding how the `warp` and `warpPoint` functions are supposed to work. What gives?

Comment: I do not know this software, but my guess is one transformation matrix is the inverse of the other. That is the projection goes the opposite direction. Point transforms usually use the forward transform and image transforms usually use the inverse transform.

Comment: You could be right, I'll give it a try. The documented names and function descriptions do not seem to imply that warp and warpPoint are related by inverse though--there are explicitly named, separate functions for that. Then again, cv2 documentation has never been particularly good in the first place...
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d76/classcv_1_1PyRotationWarper.html

Comment: one is for images, the other for points? docs say *"Projects the image."* vs *"Projects the image point."* -- the difference isn't the direction of the transform (those apis will always expect to be given the forward transform. if they need to invert, they'll that on their own.). the difference is that an image is NOT a point or a list of points. it's a grid of pixel values. those are fundamentally different.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I think in the example above I have applied the `warp` and `warpPoint` functions to point/image appropriately. It seems they both apply some transform, but the point does not get projected to the location I expect. Do have any suggestion?

Comment: why did you choose "spherical"? I am unfamiliar with the stitching module, so don't expect me to have the answer.

Comment: Fair question. "spherical" is the default for the stitching pipeline I'm using. I also tried 'plane' and the projected point still goes to somewhere crazy: [-373.64, 203.05]. Oddly, the project image and x/y maps look essentially the same in the 'plane' case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hypothesized that the first value returned by the warper.warp() was directly related with the issue. Thus, I just corrected the warped_point coordinates by subtracting the returned quantity:  warped_pt_corrected=np.array(warped_pt)-np.array(correction). After applying the correction the projection looks nice.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
from skimage import data


img = data.cells3d()[34]
img = (255.0 * img / 2**16).astype(np.uint8)[0]
img = cv2.resize(img, (300, 200))
point = [200, 100]
K = np.array(
    [[863.5509, 0.0, 446.5], [0.0, 863.5509, 336.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]], dtype=np.float32
)

R = np.array(
    [
        [0.02657406, 0.99131364, -0.12880631],
        [-0.9981135, 0.01917798, -0.05832428],
        [-0.05534741, 0.13011324, 0.9899532],
    ],
    dtype=np.float32,
)

scale = 890.0
aspect = 1.0

warper = cv2.PyRotationWarper("spherical", scale * aspect)

# warp the image
correction, warped_image = warper.warp(
    img,
    K,
    R,
    cv2.INTER_LINEAR,
    cv2.BORDER_REFLECT,
)

# warp the input point
warped_pt = warper.warpPoint(
    point,
    K,
    R,
)

w, h = img.shape[:2][::-1]

# check the maps to see where the transformed pixels came from
_, xmap, ymap = warper.buildMaps(
    (w, h),
    K,
    R,
)

# plot the example
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8))

axes[0, 0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
imx = axes[0, 1].imshow(xmap)
imy = axes[1, 0].imshow(ymap)
axes[1, 1].imshow(warped_image, cmap='gray')


warped_pt_corrected=np.array(warped_pt)-np.array(correction)

axes[0, 0].add_patch(Circle(point, 3, color='red',))
axes[1, 1].add_patch(Circle(warped_pt_corrected, 3, color='red'))

axes[0, 0].set(title=f"original image; point: {point}")
axes[0, 1].set(title="xmap")
axes[1, 0].set(title="ymap")
axes[1, 1].set(title=f"warped image: point: [{warped_pt_corrected[0]:.2f}, {warped_pt_corrected[1]:.2f}]")
cbx = plt.colorbar(imx, ax=axes[0, 1], orientation="vertical")
cby = plt.colorbar(imy, ax=axes[1, 0], orientation="vertical")

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: The image is the output of the code]

Let me also use another example to see better that the correction is appropriate:
[image: Additional example]

Comment: Nice! I guess it makes sense in a way. The top left of the warped image will always be _plotted_ as (0, 0), so we need to know the translation that relates the image (0, 0) to our coordinate space which the warped_pt lives in. It's a real shame the documentation is unclear on this.